# Android Send String to Server via retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

i want to send string from app to server with retrofit 2, and get back return values. what is the problem?
but it doesn't work.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RatingApiService retrofitService=retrofit.create(RatingApiService.class);

            Call<String> call = retrofitService.registration("saeed","ali");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    if(response!=null){
                        Log.i("upload","is success:" +response.body());
                    }else{
                        Log.i("upload","response is null");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("upload","onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Interface:

```
public interface RatingApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("android/add2/{email}{password}")
    Call<String> registration(@Path("email") String email, @Path("password") String password);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using parameters to pass your data; put it in a req.body, then send it.  By doing so, you can bypass the URL string limit and the code is much more organized.

```
public interface RatingApiService {
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json") //Must be set to application/json so req.body can be read.
  @POST("android")
  Call<String> registration(@Body UserRegistrationRequest body);
}
```

Now, you might ask what is the " UserRegistrationRequest" class? that will be the object class that will be sent as a JSON object. We define it by:

```
public class UserRegistrationRequest {
    final String email;
    final String password;

    UserRegistrationRequest(String email, String password){
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

And then the final step. This is how you convert the object to a JSON object and send it to your server.

```
       UserRegistrationRequest userRegistrationRequest = new UserRegistrationRequest(
                RegisterNameFragment.sFirstName, RegisterNameFragment.sLastName, RegisterEmailFragment.sEmail,
                RegisterPasswordFragment.sPassword, RegisterAgeFragment.sAge);

            Call<Void> call = retrofit.insertUserRegistration(userRegistrationRequest);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<UserRegistration>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UserRegistration> call, Response<UserRegistration> response) {
                    Log.d("blue", "Data is sent");

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UserRegistration> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("blue", "fail");
                }
            });
```

Comment: no data send to server,but data is empty and when i use $_POST nothing found, How can in php server  get the result. thanks

Comment: Did the android monitor said "fail" or "Data is sent"?

Comment: data send to server and say "data is sent". but in log says "Internal Server Error". in php website i have cakephp framework and just save any thing sent via $_POST, and its empty. thanks

Comment: Great, the code is working then! Internal Server Error or Error 500 implies that there is something wrong with your server. Try console.logging the body of your POST request.

Comment: Check body contents by using `$this->request` not `$_POST` in PHP.

Comment: sorry. but it doesn't work. **`$this->request`** is empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `@Body` annotation to your method like below.

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

The content of `@Body` is sent to server as request body.
If you want to send email and password to server, you should create object that contains such data and use the object in the `@Body` annotation.